# What is appropriate term for Hostel/PG where both boys and girls can live ?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering why we call it "co-ed" hostel ! 
Co-ed is an acronym for co-education I guess. But what if it's just a hostel where working men and women live. Should we call it a dormitory ?
I need a proper term to speak when I'm referring to a hostel where both men and women live.

Comment: A ***mixed dorm*** is one both for male and female. https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&ei=EoZ5WYmcBMbDgAaTuarACQ&q=mixed+dorm+&oq=mixed+dorm+&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..41j0i19k1l4.27574.28503.0.29186.7.7.0.0.0.0.77.378.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.7.378...0i22i30i19k1.a7nJ8RUBaEs

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with a co-ed hostel.  I would leave dormitory for on-campus student housing.

Comment: @Josh: Would you use the term *dorm* for a (short-term) housing facility unrelated to a school?  Like a barracks, bed&breakfast, hotel or motel? I think that is the point of the question — do we use “co-ed” (short for “co-educational”) in non-educational contexts (and, if so, why)?

Comment: @Scott- mixed dorm is used for short term stays in facilities unrelated to schools, as you can see from the attached link. Co-ed is generally used in schooling contexts.

Comment: A "hostel" by default is a mixed gender facility, so if you're looking for a single word, that's it. It would be more appropriate to specify an "men only hostel"(etc), as this is the unusual case.

Comment: "Breeding grounds", if you ask my conservative grandmother. That is how she described my mother's mixed dorm in college.

Comment: With respect to gender, is a hostel not a hotel? Your title mention children, but your question mentions adults. Do you mean to signal to guests that all rooms mix genders, rather than rooms for men and rooms for women?

Comment: It may be useful for both question and answers to be specific about where the term is to be used, or is used since words for such things aren't necessarily universal in the English speaking world. What one person calls a dorm another might call Halls of Residence for example. I'd guess from the use of co-ed that its the US, but it might help to be specific.

Comment: I suspect this is highly regional - in the UK, I'd never hear 'co-ed' to describe anything except for a school (or other education establishment), and even then mixed would sometimes be used instead. And I include that even in the context of education related things like dorms/common rooms/whatever else might possibly be separated would be called mixed. US I think uses co-ed where UK would often use mixed (or would not specify with the default being mixed).

Comment: Just call it a hostel. Without qualification, anyone can stay there. If it's important to point out that both men and women can stay there then say so explicitly - don't try to get it across with an adjective. If you have to just use an adjective then *mixed* is OK. But if you want to make clear that it is (only) for ***working** men and women* that say that explicitly.

Comment: Apparently, these terms are subject to regional usage to a greater extent than I realized. Where I am, co-ed can apply to absolutely anything, from co-ed rec volleyball to co-ed assisted living facilities. *Hostel* is fairly restricted. It refers to primitive lodging for travelers, usually cheap, and co-ed by default. It is not used to refer to employee housing. Hostels are assumed to be just a big open bunkhouse, but some are converted houses and have smaller rooms with only a few bunks per room.

Comment: *Dorms* means high density housing that lacks the accommodations of apartments, such as individual kitchens, showers or laundry. It can, and often is, used to refer to employee housing such as you find provided for seasonal workers or unaccompanied workers at remote locations.

Answer (score 1):

Taking cues from language about restrooms, and to be more welcoming of various gender identities,

## all gender dorms / all gender hostel.

You could also use **unisex**, though I very rarely ever hear the word used in any context. (According to Google Ngrams, *unisex* usage has been on the decline since 1996, though Google Trends shows a slight increase since 2004.

I would be interested to hear an answer to your secondary question; that is, the history of co-ed's being used for non-educational situations.

Comment: I have little doubt that "all gender" is the politically correct term, but I am from a generation when there used to be only two genders, so this sounds weird. In the US it must sound perfectly normal.

Comment: Must sound normal? No, it sounds contrived and forced to me in the US.

Comment: @TheNate Duly noted. Curious, though, where in the US you live. In Seattle and Philadelphia I think it would be totally normal. Or maybe it's an age thing?

Comment: I'll give you this much: Middle aged in a city that is not a megalopolis.

Comment: If the criterion is *working men and women* it says nothing about gender, in the sense of self-identification. And saying *all-gender* does not at all express the criterion that it is for *working men and women* - neither wrt age (adults) nor wrt working. *All-gender* applies equally to 12-year olds.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Shouldn't a unisex hotel sounds be for one sex and a bisex hotel be for both sexes? ;)

Comment: This is when you want a tumbleweed equivalent for answers